# Outlook People pane - show emails sent and received

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm using outlook 2010 with people pane enabled.

[image: people pane]

When looking at a certain email message i can see all emails received from this person 
Is it possible to also **see all the emails I've sent to him**?

If its not possible with people pane, any recommended alternative?